# Zend form setAttribs with json_encode

Tags: php, javascript, zend-framework

I have a zend form select element that calls a javascript function onchange. The following:

```
$element->setAttribs(array( 'onchange' => 'toggleSelect(this.value, ' . json_encode($this->_testData) . ')'));
```

The problem is, both the ZEND onchange and the json_encode use double quotes, so it becomes:

```
<select onchange="toggleSelect(1, {"foo" : "bar"})"></select>
```

Which complains about an invalid property id. I'm thinking it is the double quotes that are causing the problem, but don't know how to fix.

Comment: Your code works for me. I get `<input type="text" name="text" id="text" value="" onchange='toggleSelect(this.value, ["foo","bar"])'>`. Can you post the code for toggleSelect()? Your problem may be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$element->setAttribs(array( 'onchange' => 'toggleSelect(this.value, ' . htmlspecialchars(json_encode($this->_testData)) . ')'));
```

Using htmlspecialchars you should end up with

```
<select onchange="toggleSelect(1, {&quot;foo&quot; : &quot;bar&quot;})"></select>
```

which should be valid html and still interpret your argument as a valid JSON object.